# Ruby framework to write a API in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, sinatra

Hi I'm looking to write a multiplatorm tasks application for technical people. I want to handle as many platforms as I can (web, shell, desktop) and therefore I have decided to begin with a server/API.

I want to write it in Ruby, however i think that Rails is a bit too heavy for this, even though it would do the job. Sinatra also doesn't seem quite suited for the task.

All the server/API would do would be to translate simple requests to Database queries, and at a later stage some authentication and authorization.

So basically I want to know:

1) Should I use a REST api or a SOAP api?

2) Is there a framework for this? Or what is the closest framework avalable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the adventurous, there is also a less known project called [grape](http://github.com/intridea/grape). It is a rack based application, similar to Sinatra, but is only purposed to write API. I don't think it is mature enough to be used in serious projects yet, but it is still interesting to know.

Answer (score 5):

1) REST, SOAP is a terrible system and its support in Ruby is quite lacking.  REST, on the other hand, is basically the ruby default and takes very little effort to use, especially if you are using REST/JSON.

2) Sinatra and Rails are basically your options.  It comes down to how complex this application will be.  Sinatra can probably handle the task just fine, but Rails does much of the work for you at the expense of bloat.  You will already be taking on some of the rails bloat if you use ActiveRecord for the database.  When authentication and/or roles come into play, Rails has mature solutions for both.  Without any additional information, I'd lean towards Rails as it does much of the work for you and, when written properly, can still be fairly fast.

Comment: I'll take bloat over pain almost any day.

Comment: SOAP servers are indeed not well supported in Ruby, however neither that nor that you don't care about type safety make SOAP a "terrible system"; whether it's relevant depends on what you're building.

Comment: @thomasfedb bloat doesn't necessarily mean less pain..

Answer (score 1):

Actually SOAP is very VERY easy to implement with [AWS](http://github.com/datanoise/actionwebservice).
At the same time, REST API is also very easy to implement. 
I have written a couple of different and parallel (JSON, XML and custom format) APIs with rails. Im sure the framework stack performance will not be your bottleneck, so don't bother with worrying about performance just yet. Your first bottleneck will anyhow be database and then perhaps requests per second.

All in all i would suggest going with Rails, it has a lot of work cut out for you.

Comment: The last commit to AWS was over a year ago, so I'd be hesitant to trust it out of the box.

Comment: I haven't looked into it myself that much but there are probably similar things out there, if its not even built into rails now.

Comment: AWS was built into rails, but after the advent of REST, core kind of killed SOAP with fire.  I may just be bitter after having lost several weeks of my life dealing with poorly implemented ruby SOAP issues.

Answer (score 1):

Since this old thread still comes up high on related Google searches, I should chip in my highly biased (as co-author and user) recommendation for [Hoodoo](http://hoodoo.cloud). Unlike other offerings, Hoodoo includes an [API specification](https://github.com/LoyaltyNZ/hoodoo/tree/master/docs/api_specification) that says how API calls must be made and how they must respond; it enforces a consistency across your design that calling clients will appreciate. If you can call one API, you can call them all. Hoodoo implements a lot of the boilerplate so you can focus on meaningful service code.

We've been using Hoodoo services for over two years very successfully at Loyalty New Zealand, who run the country's largest loyalty programme. Our Hoodoo-based microservice platform handles 100% of our client transactions.

- http://hoodoo.cloud/
- https://github.com/LoyaltyNZ/hoodoo
- https://github.com/LoyaltyNZ/hoodoo/tree/master/docs/api_specification
- https://github.com/LoyaltyNZ/service_shell

Hoodoo has 100% non-trivial rspec test coverage and 100% rdoc documentation coverage. As you'll see from the above links, there's quite a lot there!

Hoodoo is a [Rack application](https://rack.github.io), so works with any Rack compatible web server. Our preferred deployment mechanism though is an indefinitely horizontally scalable arrangement based on an [HTTP-over-AMQP bridge](https://github.com/LoyaltyNZ/alchemy-flux) and an AMQP cluster of nodes each running the same collection of services, managed inside Docker containers and deployed with Fleet. The system self-load balances across the service nodes via the queue and the decoupling of front end HTTP->AMQP processor versus the AMQP->HTTP input into the Rack stack dramatically reduces the system's attack surface. We wrote the front-end component in Node and for more about this along with Node implementations of other parts of the framework concept, see the [Alchemy Framework](https://github.com/LoyaltyNZ/alchemy-framework). Alchemy Node services and Hoodoo Ruby services can coexist on the same grid happily.